# Unity 2 and Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, runtime, unity-container, design-time, xml-configuration

I am using Unity 2.0 with Silverlight 4 and RIA Services.  Is xml configuration not supported in the web project of a Silverlight Business Application? The only way I can get the resolve method of the container to work is if I register my types at runtime vs design time in the xml config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at this time - Silverlight doesn't have System.Configuration, which is the library that runs the app.config / web.config file. It would take a LOT of duplicated code to get the existing config syntax working in Silverlight.

There was a project on Codeplex to provide a XAML-based configuration system for Silverlight apps using Unity.

Update: found it - http://sonicnet.codeplex.com - I guess I had a bad link when looking before.